# Twilio TaskRouter workers ordering

Tags: laravel, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-taskrouter

I have a problem with Twilio TaskRouter, namely with operator prioritization. Now: Operators (workers) have priority (this field added to the attributes).

The problem: if a call comes in and the operator with the highest priority is busy, the call does not go to the next operator, but continues to endlessly call the operator with the highest priority.

If I turn on the second line, then a problem arises in that if the first operator is already on the line and the second is free, then the call still goes to the first operator since he has a higher priority and can receive two calls (tasks).

Necessary parameters for ordering:

1. number of active calls for this worker at the moment
2. number of attempts to reach this worker in a given that task

If I had access to these values in the order_by parameter in the workflow, then I could control the list of assignments completely.

I expect the following behavior:
We have 3 operators A (priority 1), B (priority 2) and C (priority 3).

1. If all of them are free, then the call first goes to operator A, if operator A does not answer within 15 seconds or hangs up, then transfer to operator B, the same will happen in the case of operator B, then since operator C is the last, then if he does not answer, the call must go again through this cycle, first A, then B and only then C.
2. If the call is received by operator A, then the next calls go to B, and then to C.
3. If all operators are busy, then the call goes through the second line using the distribution logic from point 1.

Maybe it's possible to send a list of workers (with my sorting) via the backend?